# use LIKE and IN with subquery in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and I have the following tables:

**User**

```
UserID     |  UserPeers   |  Gender
-----------+--------------+--------
Mike       |  Tom1, Bob1  |  M
John       |  Tom1, Greg1 |  M
Sally      |Mike1, John1  |  F
Sara       | Sally1, Bob1 |  F
```

**special_user**

```
UserID     
-------
Tom1       
John1
```

I am trying to get all users that have peers that exist in the `special_users` table.

My attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE '%' UserPeers '%' LIKE IN (SELECT UserID FROM special_users)
```

Obviously the syntax is wrong so I am not sure how I would do this?

Expected result:

```
UserID     | UserPeers    | Gender
-----------+--------------+---------
Mike       | Tom1, Bob1   |  M
John       | Tom1, Greg1  |  M
Sally      | Mike1, John1 |  F
```

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing multiple values in a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff agree with you but I do not own it.

Comment: You don't have to use academic terms like "3rd normal form" with your users. All you have to do is talk to them about indexing and how a better model makes coding easier. If, however, you want to be academic, then might I suggest [this](https://datamodelinginstitute.com/50-years-relational/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM "User" u
INNER JOIN special_user su ON u.UserPeers like '%' || su.UserID || '%';
```

It makes a JOIN between User rows and special_user rows and match when UserID is contained in UserPeers.

I added DISTINCT clause to filter duplicate rows (in case two special_user were in a UserPeers row).

Comment: This will return too many rows if one `userid` exists as a substring of another in `userpeers`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=99bc676a78a0de1924bd5337b32c8d65)

Comment: This will return 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist' unless the table was created with case-sensitive password, as ;CREATE TABLE  "User" .....', which is not the default and so statistically unlikely.

Comment: @EdStevens I didn't choose the table name, I used the name from the question.

Comment: @nachospiu - understood.  But you can absolutely use a mixed-case name with impunity, _as long as_  you _never_ (including at creation) enclose it with double-quotes.  It is quite common for people to use this construct:  'CREATE TABLE User . . .'  (note the absence of double quotes). But without the double-quotes it is still created in the data dictionary in all upper-case.  But as long as all future references are also without double-quotes, you effectively have a case-INsensitive usage.  For that reason, use of double-quotes in examples should be pointed out and qualified.

Comment: @EdStevens in Oracle, USER (user, User, useR) is a reserved word, so you must use double quotes to use it as a table name (double quotes allow case sensitive names). If I use "User" in my query it is obvious that I created the table with double quotes. In the table description (in the question) the table name is User (not USER), so why should I change it? If you forget double quotes around the table name in a query, it's no big deal, the query will fail and you can add them. I think anyone using Oracle knows this. I prefer not using double quotes in names, but many times I had to use them.

Comment: @nachospiu - you are correct about the reserved word.  I was so focused on the case-sensitivity issue that I completely missed it.  I'd say that using double-quotes to allow used of a reserved word is just as bad, if not worse.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap both the string you are matching against and the string containing the `userid` you want to match in the `,`  delimiter so that you ensure you match a complete `userid` (rather than naively using `LIKE` without considering the surrounding delimiters and only matching a partial `userid`). Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "USER" u
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   special_user su
  WHERE  ', ' || u.userpeers || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || su.userId || ', %'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "USER" ( UserID, UserPeers, Gender ) AS
SELECT 'Mike',  'Tom1, Bob1',   'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  'Tom1, Greg1',  'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sally', 'Mike1, John1', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sara',  'Sally1, Bob1, TimTom1', 'F' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE special_user ( UserID ) AS
SELECT 'Tom1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John1' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: I changed `Sally` to add a peer `TimTom1` that should not be matched even though the `Tom1` substring is included.*

Which outputs:

> | USERID | USERPEERS | GENDER |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Mike | Tom1, Bob1 | M |
> | John | Tom1, Greg1 | M |
> | Sally | Mike1, John1 | F |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4bd7c288b36162b21ac72abba1353775)*

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a sub query. almost ANSI code below. || is to concatenate strings in oracle.

```
SELECT *
FROM UserList
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM special_user
    WHERE UserList.UserPeers LIKE '%' || UserID || '%'
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6e680/18

Comment: This will return too many rows if one `userid` exists as a substring of another in `userpeers` [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a3037/1).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be splitting the comma-seperated values of the column `UserPeers` along with a *Hierarchical Query* in order to make comparisons name by name between the tables such as

```
SELECT uu.UserID,UserPeers,Gender
  FROM
  (
   SELECT u.*, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UserPeers,'[^,]+',1,level)) AS name_piece
     FROM "user" u
  CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(UserPeers,',') + 1
      AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL   
      AND PRIOR u.UserID = u.UserID ) uu
  JOIN special_user su
    ON name_piece = su.UserID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b28e71663a57d8d4ad7d16c9f3bc3091)</kbd>